# How to change search bar text color in swift tvOS

Tags: swift, xcode8, uisearchcontroller, tvos10

I am facing the strange problem with Xcode 8.0. When i deploy the same code in Xcode 7.3 the search bar text color by default white, and deploy with Xcode 8.0 the search bar text color by default black. My requirement is that i should want to change the search bar text color.

Comment: Did you solved the issue? Could you please share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8 and tvOS 10,  has introduced light and dark interface styles.  So, if you're using built in components, these components will adapt to user's interface style preference.  However, you can opt not to adapt to this change by adding "User Interface Style" (either "Dark" or "Light") in `Project > Targets > Info`

I hope this helps.